# JQuery confirm plugin auto submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I have got a jQuery confirm script and I have just a standard button in a foreach loop

```
@Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, new { @Class = "btn-group btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove complexConfirm" })

$(".confirmDelete").confirm({
title: "Delete confirmation",
text:  "Would you like to continue to delete this record? You will not be able to revert back if you confirm on the next page.",
confirmButton: "Yes",
cancelButton: "No",
});
```

The above code is working spot on, it does what its meant to, click the button pops up are you sure, hit yes it goes to page, hit no it closes.
What I want it to do is if I hit yes, I would like it to submit the jQuery on the _Delete page so basically they hit Delete button, then hit yes then it will auto submit the Delete page form and then redirect to the index again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed all I had to do was add post: true to the jquery it now looks like:

```
$(".confirmDelete").confirm({
title: "Delete confirmation",
text:  "Would you like to continue to delete this record? You will not be able to revert back if you confirm on the next page.",
confirmButton: "Yes",
cancelButton: "No",
post:true
```

as seen in documentation here is what post does here:

> post: If false (default) and no confirm handler is set, redirects the
>   user to the URL of the button/link with a GET request. If true,
>   redirects with a POST request (like a form submission).